# PCA source code in OpenCV library

Tags: opencv, pca, eigenvector, eigenvalue

## the following API function is the source code on PCA in OpenCV library:

```
static CvStatus CV_STDCALL icvCalcEigenObjects_8u32fR( int nObjects, void* input, int objStep,
                        void* output, int eigStep, CvSize size,
                        int  ioFlags, int ioBufSize, void* userData,
                        CvTermCriteria* calcLimit, float* avg,
                        int    avgStep, float  *eigVals )
```

this function is from Eigenobjects.cpp

## and I don't understand the following code:

```
    for( i = 0; i < m1; i++ )       /* e.o. annulation */
    {
        float *be = ((float **) output)[i];

        for( p = 0; p < eigSize.height; p++, be += eigStep )
            for( l = 0; l < eigSize.width; l++ )
                be[l] = 0.0f;
    }

    for( k = 0; k < nObjects; k++ )
    {
        uchar *bv = (ioFlags & CV_EIGOBJ_INPUT_CALLBACK) ? buf : ((uchar **) input)[k];

        if( ioFlags & CV_EIGOBJ_INPUT_CALLBACK )
        {
            CvCallback read_callback = ((CvInput *) & input)->callback;

            r = (CvStatus)read_callback( k, (void *) buf, userData );
            if( r )
            {
                cvFree( &ev );
                if( iev )
                    cvFree( &eigVals );
                if( buffer )
                    cvFree( &buffer );
                if( buf )
                    cvFree( &buf );
                return r;
            }
        }

        for( i = 0; i < m1; i++ )
        {
            float v = eigVals[i] * ev[i * nObjects + k];
            float *be = ((float **) output)[i];
            uchar *bu = bv;

            bf = avg;

            for( p = 0; p < size.height; p++, bu += objStep1,
                 bf += avgStep, be += eigStep1 )
            {
                for( l = 0; l < size.width - 3; l += 4 )
                {
                    float f = bf[l];
                    uchar u = bu[l];

                    be[l] += v * (u - f);
                    f = bf[l + 1];
                    u = bu[l + 1];
                    be[l + 1] += v * (u - f);
                    f = bf[l + 2];
                    u = bu[l + 2];
                    be[l + 2] += v * (u - f);
                    f = bf[l + 3];
                    u = bu[l + 3];
                    be[l + 3] += v * (u - f);
                }
                for( ; l < size.width; l++ )
                    be[l] += v * (bu[l] - bf[l]);
            }
        }                   /* i */
    }                       /* k */
```

I know PCA is by calculating the covariance matrix and its eigen values and eigen vector, but when a part of the function invokes the internal function icvCalcCovarMatrixEx_8u32fR() to calculate eigen values and eigen vector, and then "what is the purpose of the above code in [else part]"? I guess [else part] is to calculate the eigen vector, but the function icvCalcCovarMatrixEx_8u32fR() has done it,
so, is there anybody can help me to answer what's  the purpose of this code? thanks!!!